# Items from media library won't get added to a custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, media-library

So I created 2 custom taxonomies and attached these to the media post type

[image]

for 2 types default products and season products and I used them for a special page on a site where the owner can upload pictures to show off what the owner has made. For some reason I can add the terms when I edit the image, but it won't get added to the taxonomies list which stays on 0 items and I can't seem to find out why.

[image]

[image]

This is how it's made

[image]

[image]

Am I missing something or have I done something wrong?

Also if you need more info please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed my problem, the easy solution was to add to the args list just before the register_taxonomy :

```php
'update_count_callback' => '_update_generic_term_count',
```